# In Django, how can I get custom sql executed?

Tags: python, sql, django

One of django management commands is 'sql_custom' which *PRINTS* all custom sql defined for specified app. Instead of printing it I would like to *EXECUTE* it from within django. Is there any other command which allows me to do so? Let me add that 'syncdb' *IS NOT* an answer because it does many other (unwanted by me) things.

Comment: No. I don't want to perform raw query. I want django to execute custom sql placed in model.backend.sql - all at once and as django command.

Comment: I don't think you can do that through django. You could just copy it and run it straight on your database, or you could pipe the output to your database engine's command line tool.

Comment: But I don't want it to run through pipe if django can do it for me. It introduces unnecessary hassle - maybe I don't even know and care what backend engine I'm using. So I don't know which command tool to use. Maybe even such a tool is not installed or available.

Comment: why do you want to execute it from within django? This sqlcustom stuff is for setting up db. Isn't enough to just run the commands as jqproffitt suggests (when you deploy the project)?

Comment: Because if I do it from django, django will take care about differences between engines i.e. it will pick the right custom sql file for the right backend end execute it through right connection so I don't need to care.

Comment: If it's a custom SQL then how would django "take care" of the differences? How does that make any sense?

Comment: Very simple:
django follows some naming conventions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#database-backend-specific-sql-data so it chooses the right file contining custom SQL for specific database backend.

Comment: @mnowotka: Any progress? Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

```
>>> for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
...     print(p)
John Smith
Jane Jones
```

Comment: No it's not what I mean.

Comment: I don't think there is a canned solution to run your custom sql after intial syncdb run.  Seems you would need to do something like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly where you retrieve the SQL and exec it manually (possibly wrapping that in a custom management command).

Comment: No, what I have to do is to define my own custom command derived from sql_custom. All I need is just to overwrite handle_app method. But I want to know if I'm reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

In `django.core.management.sql` lives a function `sql_custom` that "Returns a list of the custom table modifying SQL statements for the given app."

```
from django.core.management.sql import sql_custom
from django.db import connection

# List of the custom table modifying SQL statements for all apps.
l = sql_custom('', None, connection)
sql = " ".join(l)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: What are the parameters for `sql_custom` ?

Comment: @cold_coder: app, style, connection. But I think this is old and outdated code. You might have a look at the file `django/core/management/sql.py` and see for yourself. ;)

Comment: Okay, I ll have a look at it. Thank you!